# Node web kit "module did not self-register" error

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

i have a code for tracking mouse movement using robotjs running fine on node but when i use the same code in node web kit it gives me "module did not self-register " . Does there any proper solution for this problem that could work for me?

I have reinstalled the node webkit with the target node.js version 0.12 and it still showing me error when I write this line "var robot = require("robotjs")"

it shows error on webkit console :-

Error message: "Module did not self-register."stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }**proto**: d ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, fine i got the solution

you need to go in the node_module/robotjs and configure the nw-gyp target by following command

nw-gyp configure --target=0.12.3
then
nw-gyp build

and this worked for me (if you get nw-gyp command not found then use npm install nw-gyp  )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It means it's built for the wrong version of node. Did you perhaps install it while running 10 then switch to 12?

Comment: yes i was using 10 than got this error and then i updated my node  to 12 to resolve this issue but it still occuring

Comment: @mayank you probably need to reinstall the module using the target Node.js version.

Comment: @robertklep i didn't get what you mean by reinstalling node.js using target  i have reinstalled the node and node  web kit and Now, if i check the node version than it shows me 0.12 the latest version of node and the web kit version is 0.12.3 . (I am using ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @mayank I meant that you need to reinstall node-webkit with the Node.js version that you intent to use it with (and also on the same OS). If you already did that, can you edit your question and post the exact error (including stack trace) that you're getting?